# tween back to auto-height with xuijs

Tags: javascript, dom, xui

I'm having problems to create a equivalent slideDown for xuijs.

The slideUp (hide) is easily done with

```
x$('elm').tween({height:'0'});
```

but there seem to be no way to revert back to original height using tween.

```
$x('elm').setStyle('height','auto !important');
```

works fine but no animation of course,

```
x$('elm').tween({height:'auto !important'});
```

does not work. (setting height to fixed value does however, but that's not an option).

Kind of stuck here, document.getElementById('target_box').clientHeight doesn't help either once the height is set to 0 by tween or setStyle. Only solution I can think of is storing the heights in an array before initial global collapse of divs.

thankful for any help.

(the divs affected uses overflow: hidden)

regards,

//t

Answer (score 1):

If you're using html5 Why not store the height as a `data-` attribute before you call tween?

```
x$.extend({
 'slideUp' : function(){
    this = this[0];
    x$(this).attr('data-h',this.clientHeight);
    x$(this).tween({height:'0'});
 },
 'slideDown' : function(){   
     this = this[0];   
     x$(this).tween({height:x$(this).attr('data-h');});     
  }
});
```

this code is untested, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: thanks for post, will try later, please se zepto-comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have solved this but I got a solution. Pretty sure there are better ways but this seemed to do the trick.

[emile.js and xui animation needing double click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130486/emile-js-and-xui-animation-needing-double-click)

uses emile instead of tween but sure you could change it if you want however emile.js is in xui.

Comment: Thanks for post but I found zepto which work otb, http://mir.aculo.us/2010/10/28/zepto-js-a-jquery-compatible-mobile-javascript-framework-in-2k-presentation/